# Removing a character from a string removes multiples of some letters, but not others

Tags: javascript

I have what I beleive to be a simeple function for removing specified letters from a string.  However, it will remove duplicates of certain letters, but not duplicates of other letters. How can this be?

```
function removeLetter(str) {
  const arr = ['u', 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'];
  let strArr = str.split('');
  strArr.forEach(function(strVal) {
    arr.forEach(function(arrVal){
      if (strVal === arrVal) {
        const index = strArr.indexOf(strVal)
        strArr.splice(index, 1)
      }
    })
  })
  return strArr.join("")
}
```

working playground link [link to a fiddle](https://playcode.io/666595/)

Comment: `str.split('').filter(x => !arr.includes(x)).join('');` Never mutate a data structure (splicing an array in this case) as you are iterating it, you will get all sorts of weird behavior like this.

Comment: much more simple, thanks

Comment: this function is inefficient because you got to loop your element 3 times each. You should really consider regex. Just replace all the vowel with a " " .

 Example : `function stringCheck(str) {
  return str.replace(/[aeiou]/gi,'');
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making changes into strArr and the possitions are not the same, so just loop `arr` first and then `strArr`

```js
 function stringCheck(str) {
    const arr = ['u', 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'];
    let strArr = str.split('');
    arr.forEach(function (arrVal) {
        strArr.forEach(function (strVal) {
            if (strVal === arrVal) {
                const index = strArr.indexOf(strVal)
                strArr.splice(index, 1)
            }
        })
    })
    console.log(strArr.join(''))
    return strArr.join("")
}

stringCheck('The rain in spain falls mainly on the plain')
console.log('===The above line gets all the a\'s but not of the i\'s==')
stringCheck('What are you, a communists son')
console.log('===The above line gets all the a\'s and o\'s but one of two u\'s==')
```

Comment: totally missed that i was mutating the array and then trying to look through it.

Answer (score 1):

How about Regexp that would replace all occurrences of `aueio`?

```js
function stringCheck(str) {
  return str.replace(/[aueio]/ig, '')
}

console.log(stringCheck('The rain in spain falls mainly on the plain'))
console.log(stringCheck('What are you, a communists son'))
```

Comment: would work too, and looks more simple, but i was trying to get a fix on what I had.